# C# Same variables, static and not, on every derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

I am working on a large scale project and to spare you of the details I will simplify to the example below. I also made this image showing vaguely what I want to accomplish although obviously with other classes and fields.

[image: An example of how I image it working]

I want to have a master class (Shape) that contains a function (draw) that all the derived classes will also need as well as a static variable (sides) that all other classes should also have although with a different value for each class.

It would also be great if I could have another base class (Polygon) that is also derived from the original base class (Shape) but that I then can also inherit from and that class should then contain some other variables shared by all it's children.

I have already tried a few things but they have not really been satisfactory:

- Abstract classes - Do not support static variables
- Inheritance from normal - Can not override static variable, base class can be instantiated **(not needed in this case)**
- Interface - Does not support fields

I am aware there are some workarounds like making functions that return the variable, just setting up properties instead of fields and setting these things in the constructor. The two first are just messy and hard to read and I will need to write quite a few both sub-classes and variables so having to write not just the variable but also a lot of essentially copy-paste code for every single one would be very tedious and I would like to avoid that if possible. The third (setting them in the constructor) also doesn't work since because of the way my project is built the constructor will behave a bit weird. (I am using Unity for this) and even though I could figure out a way this is also not as easy as I would want.

This is how I imagine it looking although it obviously doesn't work for a number of reasons:

```
public class Shape
{

    public static int sides;
    public static void draw();

}

public class Circle : Shape
{

    public Vector center = new Vector(1f, 3.4f);
    public static override int sides = 1;
    public static override void draw(){

        //Draw a circle

    }

}

public class Ellipse : Shape
{

    public Vector point1 = new Vector(5.4f, 2.5f);
    public Vector point2 = new Vector(5.4f, 1.5f);
    public static override int sides = 1;
    public static override void draw(){

        //Draw a ellipse

    }

}
```

First, thank you very, very much for reading all that. As I understand it I am breaking a few OO rules by doing this and if you have a better idea for how I can do this avoiding inheritance all together I am happy to learn that too. However I feel like this is not too weird of a thing to want to do and so I feel like there should be some way. The rest of my code structure is already figured out so this is the last piece I need and abstract classes have always worked for me in the past so I do not really know any other ways to accomplish this so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can see why you want to make `sides` static because it is the same value for each instance, but what benefit do you expect from making `draw()` static?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Oh, I have no need to make `draw()` static in this example and I can't see any reason to why I would want that in my real project either so its just `sides` that need to be static. All functions and a few fields in my real project can be non-static!

Comment: What use does `Shape.sides` have? Not all shapes have a number of sides and the number of sides that each shape has is different, so why does this static property exist?

Comment: Well, @Draco18s. First of all this is just an example so it is not really practical but I imagine that maybe you want to be able to find all the shapes with 4 sides and only draw them and that is when it is useful to have that variable. Also it is static because all shapes of the same type will have the same number of sides and in my real project this is also true and so the solutions brought up here will be useful for that!

Comment: *`Also it is static because all shapes of the same type will have the same number of sides`* That would be `Square.sides` (or `Triangle.sides` or...) which I didn't ask about, I specifically asked about `Shape.sides`: the static field of the `Shape` class (not the `Square` class).

Comment: @Draco18s Oh, well that's just the way you need to do things in C#. In order for the compiler to make sure every sub-class has the `shape` variable. In other programming languages such as JavaScript the compiler will compile the code and throw an error if the variable doesn't exist when the code runs. C# on the other hand won't do that and in order for the code to compile you need to make sure the master-class has the variable. Did that answer your question?

Comment: @KaspianR That is not how C# works. A `static` field is specific *only to that class.* "[Static methods can be overloaded but not overridden, because they belong to the class, and not to any instance of the class.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members#static-members)" `Shape.sides` has no bearing on `Square.sides`, so why do you have `Shape.sides`?

Comment: @Draco18s Right! That is why I asked this question to get some opinions on what the best solution was. I didn't really get the answer I wanted and I had to make some changes to the rest of my code in order for it to work with this system but it's good enough for now. The reason I would have liked it to be static is because of how a certain type of classes work in the Unity game engine but it it working quite well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason that you need `sides` to be static? For example, do you need to know the number of sides for a shape without having an instance?

If so, I can't see any reason for inheritance, just do `Circle.sides` or `Hexagon.sides`.

The only way to work with types and not instances is through reflection, so inheritance is not a concern.

If you are working with instances, define an abstract property then polymorphism can be used. For example:

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    public abstract int Sides { get; }
}

public class Circle : Shape
{
    public override int Sides => 1;
}

public class Hexagon : Shape
{
    public override int Sides => 6;
}

Shape[] shapes = new Shape[] { new Circle(), new Hexagon() };
foreach (Shape shape in shapes)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Shape has {shape.Sides} sides");
}
```

I can't see any reason why you would make `draw()` static, unless it is a factory method, as it would require instance variables.

Comment: Not needing an instance would be very useful because of limitations with the game engine so this isn't quite what I'm looking for although I need to thank you for learning me you could write `Sides => 1`. I had literally not idea and that will save me so much time!

Comment: @KaspianR just give every shape class a static `Sides` property, no need for inheritance, then you can check by doing `int sides = Square.Sides`, `int sides = Octagon.Sides` etc. You would never need to do `Shape.Sides` as that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yeah that seems like that is in fact the only way and with that clever way of writing it's not even too much more work. I have some things to do and if no other way have appeared when I can get to implementing it I guess I will have to go with that approach even though it was kind of the thing I tried to escape. Thank you non the less!

Comment: Or actually @JohnathanBarclay. I am having problems getting that to work... I need to use inheritance if I want to know that every `Shape` has a variable named `Sides` right? And I can not have a static variable in a abstract class as far as I'm aware so how would I be able to get the `Sides` of any `Shape` without knowing what sub-class it is nor having it be an instance? Probably just me being stupid but sorry if I was unclear with what I wanted to accomplish, english isn't my native language!

Comment: @KaspianR Only if your working with object instances and not types. Are you able to post your code where you're having problems?

Comment: Actually, @JohnathanBarclay, nevermind. Unity does this kind of instances pretty weird since there are technically two different types of instances. The ones that sit on a object and "exist" and the ones that don't do anything and so I though I had to make them in to the first type in order to use this which I don't need to. Then my question was kind of useless in the first place but I probably wouldn't have figured that out if it wasn't for this! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, you don't have to make the `Shape` class members `static` one. Make the class abstract and override the members in child classes

```cs
public abstract class Shape
{
    public abstract int Sides { get; }
    public abstract void Draw();
}
```

You can also define some common logic in this abstract class. Another option is to define `Shape` as an `interface`

Comment: Agreed, unless he needs to know how many sides a shape has without having an instance.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay That's the thing. I need to be able to get the amount of sides without having a instance. As an example: I wan't to be able to search a list of shapes and get return all the ones with `X` amount of sides without instantiating them. This is the part where I kind of regret the decision to use a game engine I have not written myself. Is there another way? Thanks for the amazingly quick reply though @PavelAnikhouski!